# What is the configuration for inter-pod communication in microk8s

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

I am setting up a set of applications using microk8s. I have two deployment resources - let us say - backend & application- Backend deployment has a service - let us say backend-service.myns.svc.cluster.local. From the pod running the other deployment (application), I am unable connect to the backend-service. Tools like ping, curl fail with Unknown host error. However, I am able to ping google.com or internet from the same (application) pod. What is the cause of the issue?

Comment: what does the command `kubectl get svc` return for your applications ?

Comment: kubectl get services returns backend-service along with its clusterIP.

Comment: can you add the output of the `kubectl get ep,pods -owide` to your original post